# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I started to learn java yesterday and I wrote the followind program which should print pairs of equal numbers, but when I run it I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at _aaaa.main(_aaaa.java:26)
```

Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;

class pair {
    int first, second;
    pair() {
        first = second = 0;
    }
    public void make_pair(int a, int b)
    {
        first = a;
        second = b;
    }
}
public class aaaa {
    public static void main(String[] idontneedthis)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = input.nextInt(), i, lg = 0;
        int[] A = new int[5010];
        pair[] B = new pair[5010];
        for (N <<= 1, i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        {
            int var = input.nextInt();
            if (A[var] > 0)
            {
                B[++lg].make_pair(A[var], var);
                A[var] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                A[var] = i;
            }
        }
        if (lg == 0) System.out.print("-1");
        for (i = 1; i <= lg; ++i)
        {
            System.out.print(B[i].first + " " + B[i].second + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong or why do I get this error. I mention that if I cut the line 26 ( `B[++lg].make_pair(A[var], var);` ) it will write -1.

Thank you!

Comment: Class should begin with a capital letter!

Comment: @JpBond correction **should**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    pair[] B = new pair[5010];
```

Only allocates the **space** for `5010` `B` elements.  You need to instantiate each element in that array.

```
for(int i = 0; i <B.length;i++)  
{  
    B[i] = new pair();
}
```

Style things:

Class names start with upper case letters:  `AAAA` not `aaaa`.
also star imports are bad:

```
import java.util.*;
```

replace with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: @user1948703 sorry forgot to include it, yes it would be import java.util.Scanner;

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialise the pairs in your array:

```
if (A[var] > 0) {
    B[++lg] = new pair(); //here
    B[lg].make_pair(A[var], var);
    A[var] = 0;
}
```

This line:

```
pair[] B = new pair[5010];
```

creates an array of 5010 pairs but until you initialise them, they are all null.

Also note that since `5010` and `N` are not related, you could get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException depending on N.

Comment: But, how can i initialize them wihout  B[++lg] = new pair(); //here this?

Comment: What do you mean? You will need to loop over the items of the array and initialise them one by one.

Comment: @user1948703 You have to initialise it some how.  Woot4Moo's answer is an alternative, but this is better.

Comment: Yes, I understand now, but to loop over all items is the only solution?

Comment: @user1948703 If you want to initialise them all, yes.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would write it. The less said the better ;)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pair {
    final int first, second;

    Pair(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return first + " " + second;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfPairs = input.nextInt();
        List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfPairs;i++) {
            int first = input.nextInt();
            int second = input.nextInt();
            pairs.add(new Pair(first, second));
        }
        for (Pair pair : pairs) 
            System.out.println(pair);
    }
}
```